# How to add security to a Custom Web Application on WSO2?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-identity-server

I succefully deployed my spring web application on WSO2 carbon, I can access it and use it without problem but it containt some sensible data.

How can I share the login security that is built in WSO2? How can I avoid external users use my web application without logging first in the WSO2?

What I want is that the users do the login first then he can use the application.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Configure WSO2 Application Server with the backend userstore(LDAP, DB, WS, etc).
2. Modify your webapp to authenticate again WSO2 AS.
3. Deploy your webapp in WSO2 AS and test.

Check this:

http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2012/07/authenticate-deployed-webapp-against-ldap-enforce-https/

For a full tutorial:

- http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/02/how-to-write-a-web-application-backed-by-wso2-middleware-part-1/
- http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/02/how-to-write-a-web-application-backed-by-wso2-middleware-part-2/